# Unable to change keyboard layout when inserting password in Linux (Fedora + Gnome)

Tags: linux, keyboard-layout

I'm using Fedora 38 with Gnome UI and GDM login screen.

I have two layouts Russian and Mozc (Japanese input)

Mozc has a direct input mode that I'm using instead of English layout. And usually it works fine, but when I'm prompted for password (in browser, when I need insert a superuser password, on login screen) Mozc dissapear and only Russian layout is able to use. And of course it is not possible to insert password.

Here are my

- `/usr/share/ibus/component/mozc.xml`

```
<component>
  <name>com.google.IBus.Mozc</name>
  <description>Mozc Component</description>
  <exec>/usr/libexec/ibus-engine-mozc --ibus</exec>
  <version>0.0.0.0</version>
  <author>Google Inc.</author>
  <license>New BSD</license>
  <homepage>https://github.com/google/mozc</homepage>
  <textdomain>ibus-mozc</textdomain>
  <!--<engines exec="/usr/libexec/ibus-engine-mozc --xml" />-->
  <engines>
    <engine>
      <description>Mozc (Japanese Input Method)</description>
      <language>ja</language>
      <icon>/usr/share/ibus-mozc/product_icon.png</icon>
      <rank>80</rank>
      <icon_prop_key>InputMode</icon_prop_key>
      <symbol>あ</symbol>
      <setup>/usr/libexec/mozc/mozc_tool --mode=config_dialog</setup>
      <name>mozc-jp</name>
      <longname>Mozc</longname>
      <layout>jp</layout>
      <layout_variant></layout_variant>
      <layout_option></layout_option>
      </engine>
    <engine>
      <description>Mozc (Japanese Input Method)</description>
      <language>ja</language>
      <icon>/usr/share/ibus-mozc/product_icon.png</icon>
      <rank>99</rank>
      <icon_prop_key>InputMode</icon_prop_key>
      <symbol>A</symbol>
      <setup>/usr/libexec/mozc/mozc_tool --mode=config_dialog</setup>
      <name>mozc-off</name>
      <longname>Mozc:A_</longname>
      <layout>jp</layout>
      <layout_variant></layout_variant>
      <layout_option></layout_option>
    </engine>
    <engine>
      <description>Mozc (Japanese Input Method)</description>
      <language>ja</language>
      <icon>/usr/share/ibus-mozc/product_icon.png</icon>
      <rank>99</rank>
      <icon_prop_key>InputMode</icon_prop_key>
      <symbol>あ</symbol>
      <setup>/usr/libexec/mozc/mozc_tool --mode=config_dialog</setup>
      <name>mozc-on</name>
      <longname>Mozc:あ</longname>
      <layout>jp</layout>
      <layout_variant></layout_variant>
      <layout_option></layout_option>
    </engine>
  </engines>
</component>
```

- `/etc/default/keyboard`

```
XKBLAYOUT=jp
```

- output of `localectl` (set by `sudo localectl set-keymap jp106`)

```
System Locale: LANG=ru_RU.UTF-8
    VC Keymap: jp106
   X11 Layout: jp
    X11 Model: jp106
  X11 Options: terminate:ctrl_alt_bksp
```

- `~/.config/mozc/ibus_config.textproto`

```
engines {
  name : "mozc-jp"
  longname : "Mozc"
  layout : "jp"
  layout_variant : ""
  layout_option : ""
  rank : 80
  symbol : "あ"
}
engines {
  name : "mozc-off"
  longname : "Mozc:A_"
  layout : "jp"
  layout_variant : ""
  layout_option : ""
  rank : 99
  symbol : "A"
  composition_mode : DIRECT
}
engines {
  name : "mozc-on"
  longname : "Mozc:あ"
  layout : "jp"
  layout_variant : ""
  layout_option : ""
  rank : 99
  symbol : "あ"
  composition_mode : HIRAGANA
}
active_on_launch: False
```

I simply want to use `JP` layout when inserting password or at least able to choose Mozc's direct input. The only possible way is to fix the problem is to add one more `Japanese` (or `English`) layout, but it is a same as Mozc's direct input and I don't to have two same layouts

Also if I remove Russian layout at all, Japanese layout is used when password inserting